# C++ SFML Client-Server Game SocketSelector Design

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, sfml, blocking

I am making a small multiplayer game, where the host player starts a server from her application which runs the game logic for everyone and displays the graphics for her. Up to 3 other players need to be able to connect(currently via TCPSocket connections) to receive game states to render on their computers and so they can send input commands to the hosts computer to update game state.

I have been able to implement connections using blocking sockets and a SocketSelector, as well I have implemented sending commands from clients that update game state, however, I do not understand via the documentation and tutorials available how I can separate the runServer code and the hosts update and render code without utilizing additional threads. I have been told that the selector should be enough such that I do not need to open new threads to keep constant game time updates. My question is a request for any examples of this style of implementation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can assign blocking sockets to the SocketSelector and then poll the SocketSelector. From the documentation, it looks like you can call `SocketSelector::wait` with a timeout of zero. It will return true if a socket is ready. Then you use `SocketSelector::isReady` to get a handle to the ready socket. You can then receive on the socket without fear of blocking.

The host can simply poll the sockets and handle responses every game loop. (Or every other...or twice per game loop... any interval you want)

Comment: So if three socket's are ready during the same game loop iteration, will this method still ensure that the game loop is not delayed if the handling of all three ready responses takes a long time?

Comment: No. In what I described, the game wouldn't continue until the handling is done. But 3 sockets isn't a lot, and I think with some simple optimizations, you could run the socket handling 60 times a second. Send fewer bytes... use UDP... Don't send serialized objects, send strings and primitives. The other pattern you could use is asynchronous writes and reads. That uses threads, but it's a bit more manageable in the caller code. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like sfml supports that.